# "WinError 32" after doing run_setup to find out package metadata

Tags: python, windows, distutils

I'm using Python 3.6.1 on a Windows dev environment without any admin rights. I have a Python program which does the following:

1. Create temporary directory using `tempfile.mkdtemp()`
2. Clone a Git repo into it
3. Build the code in the Git repo into a Python wheel
4. Install the wheel into a target Python venv
5. Delete the temporary directory using `shutil.rmtree()`

**In the 5th step (removing the tempdir) I keep getting the error:**

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file 
    because it is being used by another process: <path of tmpdir>
```

Note that this error message *seems* to concern removing the directory, not any specific file within it.

After many thankless hours of debugging I think the following line which the script has to do as part of the 3rd step seems to cause it:

```
def get_metadata(path_to_setup_py):
    return distutils.core.run_setup(path_to_setup_py, stop_after='init').metadata
```

**I am getting package metadata simulating the app setup by using `run_setup()`, but I think the function fails to close file handles or something, leading to above error.**

I read the source code for `run_setup` but it's not really intelligible to me. I *think* what is happening is that the `exec()` actually runs the complete setup.py, but calls to `setup()` are re-routed into the current process so data can be shared using the global variables `_setup_stop_after` and `_setup_distribution`.

Either way I cannot see why "another process" would keep a file/directory lock as the `exec()` should be happening inside the current process!? Note that after the script exits **the tempdir is empty and I can remove it no-problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I just needed to type this question out to immediately get an idea for the answer. Immediately before removing the tree I printed out the current working directory:

```
print(os.getcwd())
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```

And I realized that it was the directory I wanted to delete, I assume this is a side effect of `run_setup`. The solution is to **simply change the directory before deleting it!**

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Temp')
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```